# How to derive formula of variance of sample median?

Tags: variance, median, parameter-estimation

I wonder how to derive the formula of variance of median of sample.
I searched it for a day but couldn't find, so I'm asking help here. You may just notice me the link of it.

I saw the result form is

$$
Var(X-median) = \frac{\pi}{n}\times\frac{\sigma^2}{n}
$$

But couldn't find how to derive this.

Thank you genius!!

Comment: I presume that $\pi$ doesn't approximately equals $3.14159$ in this context.  So what is it supposed to be?

Comment: @MichaelHoppe What do you mean??

Comment: You used the symbol "$\pi$".  What does it represent?

Comment: @MichaelHoppe it does represent $\pi$ but I suspect the expression should be $\dfrac{\pi\,\sigma^2}{2\, n}$, and this is a large sample from a normal distribution with variance $\sigma^2$

Comment: In general for a distribution with continuous density $f(x)$ and population median $m$, the sample median $\tilde{m}$ from a sample has a mean-square deviation with $\sqrt{n}(\tilde{m}-m)^2 \to \mathcal N\left(0, \frac1{4 f(m)^2}\right)$ in distribution as $n$ increases